# Rebind grid with combobox, how to get selected value?

Tags: c#, combobox, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I work with Telerik-MVC and I'm trying to rebind a grid when I change the value of a combobox. Everything seems working except I can't get selected value of my combobox.
Here is my code :

Grid :

```
@{Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.Col1);
            columns.Bound(o => o.Col2);
            columns.Bound(o => o.Col3);
        })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
             .Select("_MyAction", "MyController")
        )
        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("Grid_onDataBinding"))
}
```

Combobox :

```
@(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
        .Name("ComboBox")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "ComboBoxCode" })
        .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.GroupBy(x => x.Code)
                              .Select(o => o.First()).ToList(), 
                              "Code", "Code"))
        .ClientEvents(events => events
                .OnChange("onComboBoxChange")
        )
)
```

Script :

```
function onComboBoxChange(e) {
    $("#Grid").data("tGrid").rebind();
}
function Grid_onDataBinding(e) {
    var code = /* I need to get the combobox value here */;
    e.data = { myCode: code };
}
```

Controller :

```
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult _MyAction(string myCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Code : " + code);
        /*
            Set new model here
        */
        return View(new GridModel(newModel));
    }
```

I tried things like :

```
var e = document.getElementById("ComboBoxCode");
var code = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

But it doesn't work. Can you tell me how to fix this problem and get the right value ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you rebind the grid, you didn't really use the ComboBox selected value. Your `onComboBoxChange` function tells the grid to rebind, which it does by going to the `_MyAction` method. At no point did you pass in the ComboBox value. What you should do is before databinding, grab the selected value and pass it to your controller action. See http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnDataBinding for details. Something like this:

```
function Grid_onDataBinding(e) {
    var combobox = $('#ComboBox').data('tComboBox');
    e.data = { code: combobox.value };
}
```

(Note that I actually haven't done any work with the ComboBox, so this isn't tested, but this should at least get you on the right path. See [ComboBox documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-combobox-client-api-and-events.html).)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. Everything seems working except I don't know how to get the selected value from combobox in my function `Grid_onDataBinding`. I edit my question for more details.

Comment: Added an example to my answer.